# How to filter with all outputs when using Rewrite results option in Views

Tags: views

In my view using the "Rewrite Result" option, I combined two fields "first name" and "Surname" to display as one field with label "Full name".

I then added an exposed filter to allow users search through the Full names.

My challenge is that it only filters using the surname and not both. How do I get users to be able to filter using both first name and surname.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter on both the Firstname and Lastname, when you want to add a filter, select  **Global: Combine fields filter,** and then click add. The next step tells you to select the fields to filter. Select your firstname and Lastname field